# Reviewing First Post Answer: Feedback Channels

Tags: discussion, review-page

I just reviewed a First Post that was classified as an answer.
It had poor spelling, grammar, a lot of ranting and so on.
If that would have been all to it I were easily persuaded to apply a *no paseran* policy to this.
However, it was a first post, it showed much frustration and as far as I could tell it possibly had at least some grain of value in it, albeit just: "'no werky' here too" (to adopt the terminology I read here).

My problem now is that I got myself confused on how to proceed. Editing seemed out of the question, I didn't know what would happen if I just commented on that etc.
What I wanted was to tell the poster what was wrong with it so that he may learn and revise that question, or delete it on his own.

I ended up flagging it as "unsalvageable" [since as an answer,](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3008/251859) I think it just was. But that user in distress is now also unsalvageable?

Isn't there a better way to give the necessary feedback?
(And btw a Reviewer's Manual?)

Comment: This was an answer to https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/244959/9058 I assume?

Comment: It was an "answer" to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some "answers" aren't salvageable, such as those which basically say "tried everything, still doesn't work, the software s*cks" or something along these lines. It's always ok to leave a comment in such cases, I tend to use something like

> You've posted this as an answer, which is only for things that directly answer the question asked. If you have a different question, feel free to ask it using the Ask Question button at the top right. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

and, if you have enough reputation, recommend deletion.

PS: Also see [Reviewing 'low quality posts' - when to recommend deletion of answer](https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/reviewing-low-quality-posts-when-to-recommend-deletion-of-answer?rq=1), and what I wrote there :-)

PPS: There is [What would be a guide to review first-post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222963/what-would-be-a-guide-to-review-first-post), and probably more stuff on meta.stackexchange.com as well

Comment: PPS-link was new to me. Both helpful. Still think a manual for these situations *and* the review page would be good.

Comment: @LangLangC There are very few rules here, besides what already has been written. If the answer tries to move the topic forward, keep/improve it; if it is off the mark, comment, delete and move on. Don't worry about getting it "wrong" sometimes, there are always several users required for a review.